# Sitecore saveUI processor redirecting to item page after moving it

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

I have implemented a Sitecore saveUI processor for moving news items to a specific location inside a year/month hierarchical structure. It does the job well, except for the fact that when used inside the Page Editor (navigating to an item's page and then trying to save, and implicitly move, the item) I am redirected to our 404 page, since Sitecore expects the original item's url to still be valid after the operation.
Is there any way to tell Sitecore that the item has been moved? I'm thinking at some property in SaveArgs, but any solution would do, as long as it's somewhat maintainable (for example, I'd prefer a server-side solution, not a client-side JavaScript-based one, if possible).

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, make sure your processor the last one in the pipeline and add the following code to the end of the process method:

```csharp
if(Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsPageEditor)
{
    var item = args.SavedItems.First() // or perhaps Context.Item;
    var url = LinkManager.GetItemUrl(item);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(url);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work. I moved the processor to the bottom of the list and added the change you suggested but I still get redirected to the 404 page.

Comment: I think it should have been `HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(url);`, typo from Martin no doubt.

Comment: Updated! Nothing like coding directly into SO :-)

Comment: Having had a look at the processors in that pipeline, I think maybe you should try putting yours before `PostAction`.

Comment: @MartinDavies Unfortunately, that did not work either. It seems that IsPageEditor is not set to true inside the processor, and, even without that condition, I'm not redirected after saving (and, implicitly, moving) an item in PE to that item's presentation component. Instead, I'm still being redirected to the 404 page.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [Sitecore Newsmover Module](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/News_mover.aspx)?
This works seamlessly and could be the way to go instead of creating custom movers. We have used this plenty of times and it does seem to work well in all conditions.

Sample config for this:

```
    <template id="User Defined/News Article" sort="Descending">
      <DateField>Posted Date</DateField>
      <YearTemplate formatString="yyyy">User Defined/Folders/Article Year Folder</YearTemplate>
      <MonthTemplate formatString="MMMM">User Defined/Folders/Article Month Folder</MonthTemplate>
    </template>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely try this out. For the time being I've scrapped my initial solution and implemented an item:creating event handler for news items. The downside of this approach is that it orders news items by creation date rather than the selected news date. I think I could at least study the code of the Newsmover module to see what was wrong in my initial implementation.