# Sitecore: Redirect on save event

Tags: vb.net, redirect, sitecore, sitecore7

Possible duplicate of [Sitecore saveUI processor redirecting to item page after moving it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24065457/sitecore-saveui-processor-redirecting-to-item-page-after-moving-it) , but since it was unresolved I will make an entry.

We want to change the title and the URL every time we change the title of an article. We have created a custom processor inside "SaveUI" that changes the item name according to the main title of the article. However when we save the item and the page reloads, we get a 404 error. We want to create a redirect to the new URL of the updated item.

Inside the custom processor:

```
Dim database = Sitecore.Context.ContentDatabase
Dim itm = database.GetItem(updatedItem.ID)
Dim url = LinkManager.GetItemUrl(itm).Replace("/sitecore/shell/Home", "")
Sitecore.Web.WebUtil.Redirect(url, False) 'Our url is correct
```

This throws: 
`A first chance exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in mscorlib.dll`

Is there another place the redirect logic can be added?

**Edit**

Also worth to mention that I want this interaction to happen in the Page Editor.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send an `item:load` message to the client to tell it to load the item:

```
Dim database = Sitecore.Context.ContentDatabase
Dim itm = database.GetItem(updatedItem.ID)

Dim load = String.Format("item:load(id={0},language={1},version={2})", itm.ID, itm.Language, itm.Version)
Sitecore.Context.ClientPage.SendMessage(this, load)
```

You may have to send `ClientResponse.Timer()` instead of `SendMessage()` to add a slight delay. You can read more information on this post by John West: [Load or Reload an Item in the Sitecore ASP.Net CMS](http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/john-west-sitecore-blog/posts/2011/08/load-or-reload-an-item-in-the-sitecore-aspnet-cms.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work. The default reload still happens. Even with the `Timer()` method. I put 1000 in delay. Also the link to the John West article is dead.